# Matlab symbols used to terminate the loop

Tags: matlab

I am new to matlab and I have couple of questions about it. First one, "Your function should terminate the sequence when either the value of ... or..." I use || in the code but it does not work as expected while && gives me the correct answer. Second question, how could the code be to display only the final answer?

Problem: calculate X which is represented by the sequence below

```
X = 1 - 1/2^2 + 1/3^2 - 1/4^2 +....
```

Requirement: Your function should terminate the sequence when either the value of `1/k^2` is less than `0.0001` or `k` is equal to `k_max`.

```
input k
Initialize x = 0
for loop i from 1 to k
     if 1/i^2<0.0001 && i >= 100
         break
     end
     Calculate X = (-1)^(i+1)./i^2 + X    
end
```

Comment: What does your code look like now?

Comment: `||` is `logical bitwise or` and `&&` is `logical bitwise and`. When you say `&&` gives you the correct answer, that means use of `logical or` is wrong at that place.

Comment: Did my solution do it for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `break` function as follows, where `END_CONDITION` is the condition you want to end your loop in.

```
if END_CONDITION
    disp(X);
    break;
end
```

To display the final answer, you can use the `disp` function. Eg. if your variable you want to print is called `A` then you use the following code.

```
disp(A)
```

Collectively this is your code. Since `k_max` terminates at the end of the for loop, we don't have to add any conditions to break out of the loop.

```
X = 0;
for i = 1:k
     if 1/i^2<0.0001 || i==100
         break;
     end
     X = (-1)^(i+1)./i^2 + X;
end
disp(X);
```

Comment: 100 is supposed to be k_max, you can terminate the sequence when k meets 100 or 1/k^2<0.0001. Will you use ' &&' or '||' ?

Comment: @user4805946 I'll add that back in then. You should use `||`

Comment: Your code does not give the correct answer, output is supposed to be 0.8224 if input is 1 .

Comment: @user4805946 What is your "input"? X? k? Is your output the final X displayed?

Comment: my output is 0.8225 if I use `||`, output is the final X. If I use ` &&` it gives 0.8224

Comment: And what's your input? You never defined what it was.

Comment: I said it before, input is 1

Comment: @user4805946 It's illogical that your output be `0.8224` if your input `k` is `1`? It converges to `0.8224` only if your `k` is high, so specify a high `k` such as `k=100`.

Comment: k being the "input" that you defined and the number of iterations to run as well.

Comment: I understand that but why the code does not give the right answer

Comment: It is giving you the right answer as far as calculating the sequence sum goes. You are not getting 0.8224 because your answer is based on some series approximation and the series is equal to the convergence with an infinite number of terms. You don't have an infinite number of terms if you use `k=1`

Comment: @user4805946 Is there anything wrong with my above explanation or is there anything I need to clarify?